# Processing calls void setup() twice, and I need a work around

Tags: processing

I'm working on a program that reads in some images (.jpg) and text from source files and assembling them into a single PDF.  I know processing probably isn't the best language to do it in, but its the only one I know how to do it in.  Anyway, I am having an issue where processing calls setup two times.  I've seen that this issue is resolved when size() is the first line within setup, however I can't have that happen, because I have to read in and store all my data, find the width of the widest image, then make sure its tall enough to accommodate pages with more than one image, and add text before I can decide on how wide and tall my window is.  I am looking for suggestions as to how I might structure the code so that I can get all my information without having to call setup twice, because that's causing my PDF to contain two copies of all the data.  I've included setup if it helps anyone.  Thanks!

```
void setup(){
  font = loadFont("TimesNewRomanPSMT-20.vlw");
  File clientsFolder = new File("C:/Users/[my name]/Documents/Processing/ExerciseProgram/Clients");
  clients = clientsFolder.listFiles();
  for(File x : clients){
    println(x.getName());
  }
  //test files to see if they end in .txt, and have a matching .pdf extension that is newer
  String nextClient = needPdf();

  File nextClientData = new File("C:/Users/[my name]/Documents/Processing/ExerciseProgram/Clients/" + nextClient);
  //println(nextClientData.getName());

  //open the file for reading
  //setup can't throw the exception, and it needs it, so this should take care of it
  try{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(nextClientData);

    while(scan.hasNextLine() ){
      exercises.add(scan.nextLine());
    }
    //println(exercises.toString());
    printedData = new Exercise[exercises.size()];
    println(exercises.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < exercises.size(); i++){
      printedData[i] = new Exercise((String)exercises.get(i));
    }

    //count the width and height
    int w = 0, h = 0;
    for(Exercise e: printedData){
      if(e.getWidest() > w){
        w = e.getWidest();
      }
      if(e.getTallest() > h){
        h = e.getHeight();
      }
    }

    //and finally we can create the freaking window
    //                                         this cuts the .txt off
    size(w, h, PDF, "C:/Users/[my name]/Desktop/" + nextClient.substring(0, nextClient.length() - 4) + ".pdf");

  }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    println("Unknown error in PApplet.setup(). Exiting.");
    println(e.getMessage() );
    exit(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the langage you're using.

Comment: I did tag it, its Processing

Answer (score 3):

How about moving all these functions to be done before setup()? Although processing usually complains that you are "mixing static and active modes", this hack seems to work at processing 2.0.1:

```
int i = beforeSetup();
int szX,szY;

int beforeSetup() {
  println("look! I am happening before setup()!!");
  szX = 800;
  szY = 600;
  return 0;
}
void setup() {
  size(szX,szY);
  println("awww");
}
```

You are essentially calling a function to fill int i just as a hack to run all the functions you want, thus having to compute whatever you want before having to set the window size.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you can resize your window after calcs are done? Once I made this sketch to see how resizing would work, it is expecting an image file, see if it can help you...

```
//no error handling for non image files!

PImage img;
int newCanvasWidth  = MIN_WINDOW_WIDTH;  // made global to  use in draw
int newCanvasHeight = MIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT;


java.awt.Insets insets;  //"An Insets object is a representation of the borders of a container"
                         //from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html

void setup()
{
  size(200, 200);   // always first line
  frame.pack();           insets = frame.getInsets();
  frame.setResizable(true);

      /// for debuging, system depende`nt, at least screen is...
  print("MIN_WINDOW_WIDTH = " + MIN_WINDOW_WIDTH);
  print("   MIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT = " + MIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
  print("   screenWidth = " + displayWidth);
  println("    screenHeight = " + displayHeight);
}


void draw()
{
  if (img != null)
  {

    image(img, 0, 0, newCanvasWidth, newCanvasHeight);
  }
}

void getImageAndResize(File selected)
{ 
  String path = selected.getAbsolutePath();

  if (path == null)
  {
    println ("nono :-|");
  } 
  else
  {

    img = loadImage(path);

        // a temp variable for readability 
    int widthInsets =insets.left + insets.right;
    int heightInsets =insets.top + insets.bottom;

        // constrain values between screen size and minimum window size
    int newFrameWidth  = constrain(img.width + widthInsets, MIN_WINDOW_WIDTH, displayWidth);
    int newFrameHeight = constrain(img.height + heightInsets, MIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT, displayHeight -20);

        // Canvas should consider insets for constraining? I think so...
     newCanvasWidth  = constrain(img.width, MIN_WINDOW_WIDTH - widthInsets, displayWidth - widthInsets);
     newCanvasHeight = constrain(img.height, MIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT - heightInsets, displayHeight -20 - heightInsets);


        // set canvas size to img size WITHOUT INSETS
    setSize(newCanvasWidth, newCanvasHeight);

        // set frame size to image + Insets size
    frame.setSize(newFrameWidth, newFrameHeight);


        //// for debuging
    println(path);
    println(" ");
    print("imgW      = " + img.width);
    println("   imgH       = " + img.height);
    print("width+ins = " + widthInsets);
    println("      height+ins = " + heightInsets);
    print("nFrameW   = " + newFrameWidth);
    println("   nFrameH    = " + newFrameHeight);
    print("nCanvasw  = " + newCanvasWidth);
    println("   nCanvsH    = " + newCanvasHeight);
    println(" ------  ");
  }

}


void mouseClicked()
{
  img = null;

  selectInput("select an image", "getImageAndResize" );
}
```